# Capitalize the first part of a string

Tags: jquery, split

Why `split` function doesn't have option for keeping separator untouched?

Here is my string:

`story 01<div>lorem</div><div>lorem</div>`

Here is the wanted result:

`STORY 01<div>lorem</div><div>lorem</div>`

So I just need to capitalize the first part (placed before the first `<div>` tag)

Here is my way:

```
let arr = string.split('<div>');
let title = arr[0].toUpperCase();
arr.shift();
newarr = [];
$.each(arr, function (i, val) {
    val = '<div>' + val;
    newarr.push(val);
});
let result = title + newarr;
console.log(result);
```

Result:
`STORY 01<div>lorem</div>,<div>lorem</div>`

Problem is a `comma` between `</div>` and `<div>`

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to match anything but `<`s, and then capitalize the matched substring:

```js
const input = `story 01<div>lorem</div><div>lorem</div>`;
console.log(
  input.replace(/^[^<]+/, start => start.toUpperCase())
);
```

This assumes that the matched string there won't contain non-tag `<`s. If it does, then it'll be a bit more complicated:

```js
const input = `story< 01<div>lorem</div><div>lorem</div>`;
console.log(
  input.replace(/^((?!<[^<]+>).)+/, start => start.toUpperCase())
);
```

For anything more complicated, probably better to use `DOMParser` or something like it rather than a regular expression, because REs and non-trivial HTML generally don't go well together.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `join` after your `split` in this way:

```js
let str = "story 01<div>lorem</div><div>lorem</div>"

let spl = str.split("<div>");

if (spl && spl[0]) spl[0] = spl[0].toUpperCase();

let res = spl.join("<div>");

console.log(res)
```

Comment: could you give me a reference for `spl && spl[0]`, pls. What is `&&` here ?

Comment: it is just for ensurance that after splitting string your `spl` and `spl[0]` is not empty.

Comment: you can skip it if you are sure that your string will contain at least one "<div>"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by retrieving the first text node within the parent element of the HTML you have and setting its content to upper case. To do this with jQuery you can use `contents()` and `filter()`, like this:

```js
$('.container').each(function() {
  var node = $(this).contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim();
  })[0];
  
  if (node)
    node.textContent = node.textContent.toUpperCase();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  story 01
  <div>lorem</div>
  <div>lorem</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  story 02
  <div>lorem</div>
  <div>lorem</div>
</div>
```

The advantage of this method over dissecting the HTML string itself, is that this won't be broken by making a change to the HTML.

This is all assuming that you cannot amend the HTML directly, as that is the best solution by far.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **.join('')** in title + newarr:

```
let string = 'story 01<div>lorem</div><div>lorem</div>';
  let arr = string.split('<div>');
let title = arr[0].toUpperCase();
arr.shift();
newarr = [];
$.each(arr, function (i, val) {
    val = '<div>' + val;
    newarr.push(val);
});
let result = title + newarr;
console.log(result);
```

**let result = title + newarr.join('');**

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Using DOMParser
const str = "story 01<div>lorem</div><div>lorem</div>";

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');

const node = [...doc.body.childNodes].map((node) => {
    if(node.nodeType === 3) return node.textContent.toUpperCase();
    const nodeName = node.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    return '<' + nodeName + '>' + node.textContent + '</' + nodeName + '>';
}).join('');

console.log(node);
```